# Cannot access string representation of ResponseBody

Tags: android, interceptor, okhttp

I have an Interceptor that monitors all the server responses I receive. In this interceptor, I want to access the response body, THEN the string representation of this response body.

My problem is that the string() method returns an IllegalStateException.

```
Interceptor authorizationInterceptor = chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        if (response != null) {
            // This is a Nullable
            ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();

            if (responseBody != null) {
                // This fails with an IllegalStateException and I cannot retrieve the string
                String responseBodyString = responseBody.string();
            }
            return response;
        } else {
            // Should not happen
            Timber.w("Cannot get the server response as a Response object");
        }


        return response;
};
```

However I can retrieve the string value if I do the following :

```
String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
```

But I am no longer protected against response.body() being null...

I know the the body cannot be read [more than once](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240) but I dont think it is related to my issue.

How can I ensure that the response body is not null, and then getting the string representation of this reponse body ?

**EDIT**

Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:398)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:392)
at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:431)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: post your response

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

`JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
String date = jObj.getString("NeededString");`